# How to force small caps/etc. within specific text in a table?

Tags: tables, small-caps

I am using XeLaTeX and need parts of my tables to be in small caps. (note: \textbf{} and \textit{} work perfectly. It is only \textsc{} that is not working.

Here is the current code that is producing normal font/text:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{SiouanAdpositions.bib}

\title{aslkdjflkas}
\author{Noah asdfadsa\\[.4cm]{Supervisory Professor: Dr. asdfadgfas}}
\date{October 5th, 2020}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{singlespace}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
\end{singlespace}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Background}
asdfasdfasdfasdf

\subsection{Research Methodology}

\section{Evidence from Lakhota-Dakota-Nakota}
\subsection{Overview}

\subsubsection{The Derivation of Adpositions}
\label{DerivationofLDNAdpositions}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
/hakáb/ & /ihakáb/                            \\
'afterwards' (\textsc{adv})   & 'behind, after' (\textsc{adp})                      
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
/mahél/  & /i-máhel/                            \\
inside   & \textsc{adp}-inside \\
'inside' & 'inside'                            
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\subsection{Free Postpositions}

\subsubsection{Pronominal Incorporation}


\subsection{Compounds and Enclitics}
\subsubsection{Preliminaries}


\subsubsection{Compounds}


\subsubsection{Enclitics}


\subsection{Applicatives}
\label{LDNApplicatives}


\section{Evidence from Catawba}
\subsection{Overview}

\subsection{Proclitics}


\subsection{Free Postpositions}


\subsection{Enclitics and Complex Incorporation}
\subsubsection{Enclitics}


\subsubsection{Complex Incorporation}


\subsection{Post-Verbal Adpositions}


\subsection{Relationship to Applicatives}


\section{Evidence from Crow}


\section{Conclusions}

\pagebreak
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={References}
]
\end{document}
```

This does not produce "adv" nor "adp" in smallcaps.

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you so much!!

Update: I am using the latest editions of MacTeX, TexMaker, and the packages listed in the preamble.

Error:

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/sc' undefined (Font) using` TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead on input line 63.
[6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12]

Comment: As posted, your code renders the strings `adv` and `adp` in small-caps; everything else is rendered in the default text font weight (medium) and shape (upright, serif). If that's not what you want, please provide more information about what you need to achieve.

Comment: @Mico hmm, for me they are not in smallcaps. I've posted a screenshot to the question.

Comment: @Mico Oh, also, I should note that it works perfectly with \textbf{} and \textit{}. The only thing that does not seem to work is \textsc{} :(.

Comment: You mentioned in a comment that you "copied code from a very large document" into the code chunk shown in your query. Could it be that your real document contains font-related directives that are preventing `\textsc` from working as expected? For sure, I continue to experience no problems at all getting `adv` and `adp` rendered in small-caps when I compile your code (under XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and pdfLaTeX) on various machines. Please share some information about your computing setup: Which OS and which TeX distribution do you employ? When did you last update the TeX distribution?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I apologize! It is honestly just confusion, not rudeness. Is the document still non-working? I think the document works for me, just not the small caps. I am also unsure of what you mean by "using the standard font setup that does not have small caps." I truly do not mean to waste your time; I honestly do not know what you are talking about. I'm brand new to LaTeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Gotcha! I believe I have added what you mean, but let me know if I did not! Thank you!!

Comment: perhaps your Mac times font doesn't have small caps, try `TeX Gyre Termes`  a clone Times that is in tex live

Comment: I cleaned up most of my older comments as no longer relevant:-) Thanks for clarifying the question,  `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} ` should probably work for you,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle solved! It's a problem with TNR, which is so weird because I use small caps with it in pages and word all the time... Thank you!!

Comment: It may be that Word Fakes small caps by scaling full size (actually fontspec can do that if you ask it) but by default (and usually better) it only uses small caps if it can fins a small caps font

Answer (score 1):

@DavidCarlisle was able to solve my problem in the comments!

It appears to be a problem with the Times New Roman font on Mac. Using another font should solve the problem if you run into something similar :).

If I figure out how to fix the Mac Times New Roman problem itself, I will add it in an addendum.

Comment: Which version of Times New Roman? A newer one should have small caps.